# js file not working with bootstrap in vs code

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement a progress bar in which I am using the progressbar using the bootstrap and then I am creating my own js file in whihc I am trying to access the width of the progress bar and change it in interval of some seconds so it will look like a running progress bar but when I am calling my js function with on click property of the button it is not calling the function I have written in my js file.Also it is not considering the code written in my css file. The below is the code -

My head section of the html file -

```
    `<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Document</title>
      {% load static %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'file1.css' %}" />
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"         id="bootstrap-css" />
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'first.js' %}"></script>
    </head>`
```

Code in my js file -

```
`function status_move() {
  console.log("hsdfs")
  var elem = document.getElementByClassName('myBar');
  elem.style.display = 'block';
  console.log(elem2.style.display);
  var elem2 = document.getElementByClassName('myProgress');
  console.log(elem2.style.display);
  elem2.style.display = 'none';
}`
```

//Here I am printing random things just to check it is getting called or not

My progressbar code -

```
`<div class="myBar" style="
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-top: 0px;
      ">
    <div class="myProgress" style="display: block">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75"
        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">
        Preparing Your Document
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

Button calling the function in js file -

```
`<form action="/view/" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button class="button-73" onclick=status_move() value="{{n.6}}" name="b2" role="button">
                View
              </button>
            </form>`
```

On clicking this button there is nothing printing on the console which means that it is not calling my js file.

Comment: How do you open your html page ? is it running on a web server ?

Comment: No just on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEP 1**

If you move the button out of the `<form>`, you'll get the following error: `document.getElementByClassName is not a function`.

Change this...

```
var elem = document.getElementByClassName('myBar');
```

...to this.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('myBar')[0];
```

**STEP 2**

Then you'll get the following error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')`.

You need to change the order. You can't console log **before** you set the style.

Wrong:

```
console.log(elem2.style.display);
elem2.style.display = 'none';
```

Correct:

```
elem2.style.display = 'none';
console.log(elem2.style.display);
```

See the snippet below.

```js
function status_move() {
  console.log("hsdfs")
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('myBar')[0];
  elem.style.display = 'block';
  console.log(elem.style.display);
  var elem2 = document.getElementsByClassName('myProgress')[0];
  elem2.style.display = 'none';
  console.log(elem2.style.display);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="myBar" style="
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-top: 0px;
      ">
  <div class="myProgress" style="display: block">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">
      Preparing Your Document
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form action="/view/" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button class="button-73" onclick="status_move()" value="{{n.6}}" name="b2" role="button">
    View
  </button>
</form>

<button class="button-73" onclick="status_move()" value="{{n.6}}" name="b2" role="button">
  View
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try and get back to you. I have a query regarding the [0] which you used . Why to use that and what is the concept behind it ?

Comment: Because `getElementsByName()` returns a collection of elements with a specified name. To get the first one add `[0]`, to get the second one (which you don't have) add `[1]` etc. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). If this solves your problem, I would be very happy if you [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow). :)